# Jquery datepicker calendar icon positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using the jquery-ui datepicker. The problem is, the library inserts the calendar icon straight after the input field by default. But my HTML markup is a bit different and I want the calendar icon to appear somewhere else in the DOM, i.e. outside the parent container of the input field.

I even tried to add my own `<img/>` manually and added the class `ui-datepicker-trigger`, but it doesn't trigger anything.

How can I decide where the icon should appear in the DOM and it has to work?

This is what I want:

```
<div class="parent">
    <input id="datepicker" class="hasDatepicker" type="text" />
</div>

<img class="ui-datepicker-trigger" src="images/calendar.gif" alt="..." title="..." />
```

Not this (default jquery-ui insertion):

```
<input id="datepicker" class="hasDatepicker" type="text" />
<img class="ui-datepicker-trigger" src="images/calendar.gif" alt="..." title="..." />
```

Many thanks

Comment: @Kasyx, I don't want to do that because, that's what causes the insertion straight after `<input/>`. That's what I asked in the question, how to cancel that default behaviour...

Comment: Yes sorry, my fault. Now i understand your problem.

Comment: No problem, it's cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to manually add trigger which will show datepicker on image click:

```
$("#datepickerImage").click(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker( "show" );; 
});
```

Comment: this doesn't work, nothing appears. In firebug, it doesn't something to the datepicker container but it's not populated with all the date numbers, months, etc...

Comment: have you added `$("#datepicker").datepicker();` somewhere before?

Comment: ive also updated answer, please check `$("#datepicker").datepicker( "show" );`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(selector).datepicker({showOn: 'button', buttonImage: 'img/cal.gif',
      buttonImageOnly: true, buttonText: 'Open calendar'});
```

[**SEE HERE**](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/altering-position-of-datepicker-icon)